# maven install file manually without version

Tags: maven-2, jar

How do I add a jar file to my local repository without appending the version number to the jar file?

Lets say I have a jar file named abc.jar and run the following command, it will create abc-1.0.jar and if I bundle this artifact in a war file, the resulting file name will be abc-1.0.jar. If I remove the -Dversion, the command fails. If I mention blank value -Dversion="", then abc-.jar is created. How do I keep the original jar's filename(abc.jar)?

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="d:\abc.jar" -DgroupId=grp1 -DartifactId=art1 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: You can't add a file to your repository without a version (even if it is your local repo). Version management is part of Maven core and can't be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the name of the arifact in your maven repository, but you can configure the `war` plugin to use a specific nming scheme for the libs it bundles in `WEB-INF/lib` using the [outputFileNameMapping](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputFileNameMapping) option. To remove version information and classifiers the [mapping pattern](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html) would be `@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@`. If the artifact id matches the original filename this should give the wanted result.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I add a jar file to my local repository without appending the version number to the jar file?

You can't.

Answer (score 1):

This works for war packages. I haven't tried it for jars.

```
<build>
<!-- Ensures that the version number is not included in the packaged file name -->
<finalName>myrenamedpackage</finalName>
</build>
```